# Solution No Such User Here error

Tags: email

I am battling to find a definitive answer and solution to this problem, pulling my hair out stage.

I have several Wordpress sites that have forms within these. Essentially, the form is completed and an employee receives a notification with the details, pretty simple. The employees do not receive the notification emails at all, but when I use my personal email or Gmail it works perfectly!

I am seeing the No Such User Here error via my hosts webamail as per the below. I'm told that all emails are whitelisted and shouldnt be block, but they say they dont see the emails hitting their gateway.

I'd really appreciate some help here to move on with this thing, thanks in advance.

**Error message:**

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

rcook@csgroup.org.au
    No Such User Here

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

```
Return-path: <gravityforms@ampedmediaworks.com>
Received: from amwrrc by gator41.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.80)
        (envelope-from <gravityforms@ampedmediaworks.com>)
        id 1ThUzf-0007gH-00
        for rcook@csgroup.org.au; Sat, 08 Dec 2012 18:43:42 -0600
Received: from 60.228.85.149 ([60.228.85.149])
        (SquirrelMail authenticated user gravityforms@ampedmediaworks.com)
        by gator41.hostgator.com with HTTP;
        Sat, 8 Dec 2012 18:43:42 -0600
Message-ID: <ec0f41d26aad8a08452d013018cd32db.squirrel@gator41.hostgator.com>
Date: Sat, 8 Dec 2012 18:43:42 -0600
Subject: test
From: gravityforms@ampedmediaworks.com
To: rcook@csgroup.org.au
User-Agent: SquirrelMail/1.4.22
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Importance: Normal

test
```

Comment: Were you actually able to solve this issue? If so could you provide details. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with Your IP being on blacklist

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a60.228.85.149

Comment: Thanks for that Gustek. All seems fine here, zero results. I'm wondering if there may be an issue with regard to A records. The owners of the domain names wanted to set this up where I host the sites and map via A record set up. My host tells me everything is correct their end, just a thought.

Comment: It showed me that IP from headers 60.228.85.149 is on blacklist.

Comment: I was looking at the hosts IP, HostGator. That IP is my personal provider, largets company in Australia, thats odd? Thanks again.

Comment: If You have dynamic IP it is fine. But as it may be a reason why You can't send it from home, on production there may be different error. PS: I assume it's 100% email rcook@csgroup.org.au exists.

Comment: I believe it is but will double check. Yes that email is very much active, thanks again.